# PolyKinds in GADT constructors

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt

I can write

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, ConstraintKinds #-}
module Foo where

import Data.Proxy

data Foo :: (* -> *) where
    Foo :: (c a) => Proxy c -> Proxy a -> Foo a
```

but a common generalization of this pattern is

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, ConstraintKinds, PolyKinds #-}
module Foo where

data Foo :: (* -> *) where
    Foo :: (c a) => (proxy :: k -> *) c -> proxy a -> Foo a
```

where I mean for `proxy` to have the polymorphic kind `forall k . k -> *`, just like `Proxy`, but GHC 7.8 complains:

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘c’
The first argument of ‘(proxy :: k -> *)’ should have kind ‘k’,
  but ‘c’ has kind ‘k0 -> Constraint’
In the type ‘(proxy :: k -> *) c’
```

So even with `PolyKinds` and an explicit kind signature, GHC is considering `k` to be a fixed type instead of a polymorphic type. What's going on here, and is there any way to use `proxy` like I want?

Comment: The (theoretical) type you want for Foo is `forall (proxy :: forall (k :: Box) . k -> *) c . (c a) => proxy a -> proxy c -> Foo a`. You can't write this type in Haskell (yet). You'll find it has nothing to do with the GADT - you won't be able to write `test :: c a => proxy c -> proxy a -> ()` either. The simple solution is just use `c a => proxy0 c -> proxy1 a -> Foo a` - after all, you really don't care about what those proxy's will be.

Comment: Is there a ticket or other documentation for this somewhere?

Comment: Documentation for what exactly? I believe that writing the theoretical type signature would require dependent types. If you want to know about dependent types in Haskell, start [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DependentHaskell).

Comment: The current behaviour is somewhat documented at https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism.html

Comment: I'd use distrinct proxy variables, as in  `Foo :: (c a) => proxy1 c -> proxy2 a -> Foo a`. Forcing `proxy1=proxy2` *at different kinds* does not lead to anything really useful, IMHO.